# Problems configuring ckeditor with iframe.ly

Tags: configuration, ckeditor

I'm trying to configure CKEditor to use my iframely account instead of the default account.

I have a developer's api key for iframely, and have put the following into config.js:

config.embed_provider = 'https://iframe.ly/api/oembed?url={url}&callback={callback}&api_key=MyAPIKey';

However, CKEditor still uses the default iframely account.

Can anyone help?  I assume I'm missing something simple.

Comment: The code looks good. Could you create a sample on jsfiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: I'm not really sure how I could include ckeditor and extensions in jsfiddle.  I would also have to include my api key to demonstrate this.

Comment: You can add [this](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.8/standard-all/ckeditor.js) and simply use `config.extraPlugins`.